# iOS 9 Swift Segue from TextField

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am trying to start a UIActivityIndicator as soon as the user clicks "enter" on the UITextField. Since once they hit enter the app fetches for information stored in the web, i would like the user to know the app is working.

The web fetch happens inside the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier function, given that based on the results the segue will or will not happen.

So, what is the order of methods that get called starting when the user clicks on the return key. I want to start the UIActivityIndicator at that exact moment. I tried the "textFieldDidEndEditing and textFieldShouldReturn" but both of them happen after PrepareForSegue and ShouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not call the code in `textFieldShouldReturn` itself?

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    //Do the web stuff
    if shouldPerformSegue == true {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Some Identifier", sender: self)
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Ohh, so instead of calling the web stuff in the shouldPerformForSegue, I should call it in the textFieldShouldReturn? But wouldn't that be calling self. self.performSegueWithIdentifier given that it gets called before the textFieldShouldReturn?

Comment: If you call self.performSegueWithIdentifier in textFieldShouldReturn, then shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifer will run afterward.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to do something that won't work. You can't do an async network transaction in shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier and use the results of that transaction to decide if you want to perform the segue or not.

Don't invoke the segue at all.

Use a textFieldShouldReturn method. In that method, always return TRUE, display the activity indicator, and start the network request. When the request completes get rid of the activity indictor and trigger the segue (or, if the network request fails, or returns a result where you don't want to segue, then display a message to that effect and **DON'T** segue.)